# Nth Fibonacci number using 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, sequence, fibonacci

How can I do something like this? I need to create a Fibonacci class with one next () method returning the next Fibonacci string value.
Subsequent calls should return: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, etc.

The program takes an integer from the user and returns the specified number of string values. Calculations should be made using arrays.

```
public class Fibonacci {
    final long[][] A = {{1, 1}, {1, 0}};

    public static void  main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter the n th word of the sequence: ");
        long n = initialStatement(readValue());

        Fibonacci f = new Fibonacci();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            long[][] b = f.next();
            System.out.print(b[0][1]);
        }

    }


    public static long readValue() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        return scanner.nextLong();

    }

    public static long initialStatement(long n) {
        do {
            if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
                return n;
            } else if (n < 0) {
                System.out.print("Wrong value, please enter correct value: ");
                n = Fibonacci.readValue();
            }
        } while (n < 0);
        return n;
    }

    public long[][] next() {

        long[][] a =new long[2][2];


        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                    a[i][j] += a[i][j] * A[j][i];
            }
        }
        return a ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you used 2 by 2 matrix? What is the meaning of each element?

Comment: Why does this code use arrays at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is confusing.

Here is a simple alteration of your code with two int instead of matrix.

Test it and let me know.

```
public class Fibonacci {
    long i = -1; // clone of the loop counter i
    long fibo1 = 1;
    long fibo2 = 1;

    public  void  main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter the n th word of the sequence: ");
        long n = initialStatement(readValue());

        Fibonacci f = new Fibonacci();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(f.next());
        }

    }


    public static long readValue() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        return scanner.nextLong();

    }

    public static long initialStatement(long n) {
        do {
            if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
                return 1; // fibo(0) == fibo(1) == 1
            } else if (n < 0) {
                System.out.print("Wrong value, please enter correct value: ");
                n = Fibonacci.readValue();
            }
        } while (n < 0);
        return n;
    }

    public String next() {
        i++; // simulation of loop i because it is not a param of next()
        if(i >= 2) {
            long aux = fibo1 + fibo2;
            fibo1 = fibo2;
            fibo2 = aux;
        }
        return ""+ fibo2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fibonacci is a sequence that can be described by:

```
fibo(0) = 0
fibo(1) = 1
fibo(n) = fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2)
```

In code, the most simple implementation does not use matrices. You can do something like this in your class:

```java
private int a = 0;
private int b = 0;

public void next() {
    
    // Special case: Return 0 as first number in the sequence.
    if(a == 0 && b == 0) {
        b = 1;
        return 0;
    }

    // Return the sum of the last two numbers, and store the new last two numbers in a and b.
    int result = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = result;
    return result;
}
```

That will return the Fibonacci sequence starting at 0.